# What is _ga in url path?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, links, tracking

I just opened a link which leaded me to a root (main) page of www of some Organization (let's call it `XXXXXXX`). It was opened from 3rd party www, not from with `XXXXXXX`'s www.

The url in web browser has this structure:

```
http://www.XXXXXXX.org.pl/?_ga=1.123456789.123456789.123456789
```

I suspect that the `ga` stands for Google Analytics and the numbers enable owners of `www.XXXXXXX.org.pl` to check where that page was opened from, am I right?

How that "enable ... to check where that page was opened from" actually work?

Answer (score 4):

This is needed for cross-domain-tracking, and yes, it stands for google analytics.

You can't stop Google from adding the tag, but you can tell Analytics to ignore it in your reports.